# Draggable.create - Want show/hide toggle on certain array/endvalues

Tags: javascript, rotation

I've hit a snag during a project I've been working on for quite some time. The client wants a spinnable dial on his frontpage, like a safe combination dial or a volume knob.

The knob has 4 endvalues, to which the object snaps (to the nearest value). The problem I've hit is that I have no idea how to make JS toggle a hide/show on a certain element once its corresponding value has been reached.

For instance, at 90 degrees rotation, I want element X to show. At 180 degrees rotation, I want element X to hide and Y to take its place/to show. Repeat in 90 degree increments for Z and A.

My current code attempt (amongst many) looks like this

```
var dialarray = [0,90,180,270]; 

var rotationSnap = 90;
Draggable.create("#Stage_Group", {
    type:"rotation", //instead of "x,y" or "top,left", we can simply do "rotation" to make the object spinnable! 
    throwProps:true, //enables kinetic-based flicking (continuation of movement, decelerating after releasing the mouse/finger)
    snap:function(endValue) { 
        //this function gets called when the mouse/finger is released and it plots where rotation should normally end and we can alter that value and return a new one instead. This gives us an easy way to apply custom snapping behavior with any logic we want. In this case, just make sure the end value snaps to 90-degree increments but only when the "snap" checkbox is selected.
        return Math.round(endValue / rotationSnap) * rotationSnap;

if (rotation("#Stage_Group") = 90) {
    sym.$("brand_awareness").show();
} else {
    sym.$("brand_awareness").hide();
}
}
})
```

I'm using Greensocks, where support has been lacking to get me the right answer, so with some help from a more code-savvy friend (who didn't figure it out either) I turn to StackOverflow.

Can somebody please guide me to the solution here? It's driving me bonkers, even if it means ditching the current code for a working code will do, maybe I overlooked another, more logical solution towards making a rotatable object with triggers at certain values?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hmm, well I see you are doing some code after a return statement.  Try it before.  Is sym. a Greensocks thing?

Comment: Doesn't work either. It even disables the ThrowProps.

Comment: Can you try the code I put in the answer?  The ThrowProps plugin requires a license so I can't try for myself.

Answer (score 1):

This would be the code inside your snap.  Updated seeing your comment

```
var imgRotation = Math.round(endValue / rotationSnap) * rotationSnap;
if (imgRotation == 90) {
   sym.$("id1").show();
} else if (imgRotation == 180) {
   sym.$("id2").show();
} else if (imgRotation == 270 ) {
   sym.$("id3").show();
}
else if ((imgRotation >= 360) || (imgRotation == 0)){
   sym.$("id4").show();
}
return imgRotation;
```

Comment: Without the var that works! Now for the next challenge. I need four of these in total. 

(rotation = 90)
(rotation = 180)
(rotation = 270)
(rotation = 360)

I tries copying this code and replace the rotation and element and it will only show one. How can I put all four of them in there and working?

Comment: updated code above.  not entirely sure about the last if block.  can it go over 360 or is it 0?  i've update this a bunch of times, coding in a comment window is tough

Comment: I can imagine that! But your help en effort is very much appreciated. 

Now the ThrowProps is disabled and the show/hide does not work anymore :-(. I am sensing that you are going to be my hero.

Comment: fixed another typo.  the return statement was the old variable name.  try again

Comment: That did not made a difference. Aren't we missing the "hide" function now?

Comment: You'd probably want to hide all of the divs any time you spin, then wherever it lands it will show the correct div.  So before the top var, you could just have the 4 or whatever lines to hide them all..  Is the spin breaking right now?

Comment: The divs are set at "display off" in Adobe Edge. It does spin now, but without the ThrowProps.

Comment: Started tinkering with someone else's codepen which doesn't use snap.  Not sure if optimal, but I added some div's in and added code to hide/show them.  See if you can use this.  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Qbbjab

Comment: Hey, 
Firts of all, thx a lot! It does rotate, but unfortunately still no show/hide at the set degrees. :-(

Comment: That codepen I sent you hide/shows divs in the top left hand corner

Comment: I see. I changed the Id's with the elements. So I probably did something wrong? Now I really feel like a noob here... 

The thing I am creating is visible here : 
[link](http://desirecode.businesscatalyst.com/index.html)

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle?